# Very slow "update table" operation on Postgres

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing

I'm using Postgres 9.2, for some reason I've a problem with very slow updates on a relatively small table (16k rows). This is the table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE my_categories (
  id SERIAL,
  category_id INTEGER,
  is_done SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
  expected_number_of_flags INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  number_of_flags INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  is_active SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT my_categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX my_categories_idx ON my_categories USING btree (category_id);
```

And here are the stats for update some row:

```
explain analyze 
update my_categories
set expected_number_of_flags = expected_number_of_flags + 1 
where category_id = 96465;

Update on my_categories  (cost=4.27..8.29 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=199746.281..199746.281 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_categories  (cost=4.27..8.29 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=50.937..51.193 rows=1 loops=1)
      Recheck Cond: (category_id = 96465)
      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_categories_idx  (cost=0.00..4.27 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1.600..1.600 rows=6167 loops=1)
            Index Cond: (category_id = 96465)
Total runtime: 199746.339 ms
```

Can you explain what's going on and how can I improve the performance of this update?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the FILLFACTOR to 70 or 60 which is by default set to 100 as of now like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_categories SET (FILLFACTOR = 70);
VACUUM FULL my_categories;
REINDEX TABLE my_categories;
```

And then you can try to run the update query.

Comment: Question - is this flag useful also for tables that rows are keep deleted and re-inserted or only for Update operations?

Comment: @Seffy:- It will be helpful for the manipulation, for delete as well